# Mysql get data from two table from different database in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have two databases on same server with the same SERVER IP but both database user and its password is different. My problem is I want to create a procedure in which one table is used from db1 and one table is used form db2 like :

```
select * from customer; // db1
select * from orders inner join customer on order.customer_id = customer.id; // db2
```

I don't know how I can connect these two databases in one stored procedure. Basically how to create the procedure for that.

Answer (score 0):

We can access other databases on the same MySQL instance by prefixing database names to tables.

```
select * 
from db2.orders o
inner join db1.customer c
on o.customer_id = c.id;
```

> but both database user and its password is different

We might grant a role or account which can access both databases to access those resources, the user used to run the query will need `SELECT` access to all databases at least.

Comment: But how this db1 and db2 connect with server in MySQL workbench when writing store procedure

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql [federated storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-description.html) to load one of the databases required table into the other one, and then treat it like normal table.